# maven-jaxb2-plugin two xsd with same elements

Tags: java, jaxb, pom.xml, maven-jaxb2-plugin

i have two xsd(samples are simplified):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xs:schema targetNamespace="http://someurl.com" xmlns="http://someurl.com" xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" elementFormDefault="qualified">
    <xs:element name="Request">
        <xs:complexType>
            <xs:sequence>
                <xs:element name="Users" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1">
                <xs:complexType>
                    <xs:sequence>
                        <xs:element name="User" type="UserType" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="unbounded"/>
                    </xs:sequence>
                </xs:complexType>
            </xs:element>
            </xs:sequence>
        </xs:complexType>
    </xs:element>

    <xs:element name="UserType" type="xs:string" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1">
        </xs:element>
</xs:schema>
```

and

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xs:schema targetNamespace="http://otherurl.com" xmlns="http://otherurl.com" xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" elementFormDefault="qualified">
    <xs:element name="Request">
        <xs:complexType>
            <xs:sequence>
                <xs:element name="Users" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1">
                <xs:complexType>
                    <xs:sequence>
                        <xs:element name="User" type="UserType" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="unbounded"/>
                    </xs:sequence>
                </xs:complexType>
            </xs:element>
            </xs:sequence>
        </xs:complexType>
    </xs:element>

    <xs:element name="UserType" type="xs:string" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1">
        </xs:element>
</xs:schema>
```

What i need is to generate Request element into different packages or same package with different class names (if it is possible). And all child elements into same package, so for example it won't generate two classes named UserType.

This is how i generate it now in pom.xml (but in this case its problem because there are generated two different classes of UserType):

```
<execution>
                    <id>xsd1</id>
                    <phase>generate-sources</phase>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>generate</goal>
                    </goals>
                    <configuration>

    <schemaDirectory>src/main/resources/xsd</schemaDirectory>
                        <schemaIncludes>
                            <include>xsd1.xsd</include>
                        </schemaIncludes>

   <bindingDirectory>src/main/resources/xsd</bindingDirectory>
                        <bindingIncludes>
                            <include>edu.xjb</include>
                        </bindingIncludes>
                        <generateDirectory>${project.basedir}/target/generated-sources/jaxb/schemas/xsd1</generateDirectory>
                        <generatePackage>mainpackage.package1</generatePackage>
                        <plugins>
                            <plugin>
                                <groupId>org.jvnet.jaxb2_commons</groupId>
                                <artifactId>jaxb2-basics</artifactId>
                                <version>0.9.4</version>
                            </plugin>
                        </plugins>
                        <args>
                            <arg>-Xequals</arg>
                            <arg>-XhashCode</arg>
                            <arg>-XtoString</arg>
                        </args>
                    </configuration>
                </execution>
```

and

```
<execution>
                        <id>xsd2</id>
                        <phase>generate-sources</phase>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>generate</goal>
                        </goals>
                        <configuration>
                            <schemaDirectory>src/main/resources/xsd</schemaDirectory>
                            <schemaIncludes>
                                <include>xsd2.xsd</include>
                            </schemaIncludes>
                            <bindingDirectory>src/main/resources/xsd</bindingDirectory>
                            <bindingIncludes>
                                <include>edu.xjb</include>
                            </bindingIncludes>
                            <generateDirectory>${project.basedir}/target/generated-sources/jaxb/schemas/xsd2</generateDirectory>
                            <generatePackage>mainpackage.package2</generatePackage>
                            <plugins>
                                <plugin>
                                    <groupId>org.jvnet.jaxb2_commons</groupId>
                                    <artifactId>jaxb2-basics</artifactId>
                                    <version>0.9.4</version>
                                </plugin>
                            </plugins>
                            <args>
                                <arg>-Xequals</arg>
                                <arg>-XhashCode</arg>
                                <arg>-XtoString</arg>
                            </args>
                        </configuration>
                    </execution>
```

Comment: Where is the `UserType` defined?

Comment: it is defined in both xsd files, in fact it's the same element

Comment: These XSDs have different namespaces so this is not the same type. Maybe you should start by posting something minimal *yet* complete.

Comment: I have edited xsd. So in this example plugin will generate java class UserType two times and what I need is to generate it only once. So I could use same method f.e.: extractData(UserType userType) for both request types

Comment: You can use `<jaxb:class ref="ExistingClass"/>` binding.
Alternatively you can write a `UserType` interface and make both schema-derived types implement it (using the Inheritance plugin from JAXB2 Basics, for instance).